# Is there a way to two rows to one row two column postgressql?

Tags: postgresql, case

i have a table as below

```
in_out  |        date           | shift_id
02      | "2020-06-19 12:51:03" | 5311     -> this is a out
01      | "2020-06-19 10:51:03" | 5311     -> this is a in
```

expected results

```
sign_in                          | sign_out 
2020-06-19 10:51:03              |  2020-06-19 10:51:03
```

tried string_agg, inner_join

Thank you

Comment: Please include a larger sample data.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Provide the desired output.

Comment: Is "sign in" always `01` and "sign out" always `02` in the column `in_out`? And why is the timestamp for "sign_out" in your expected result the same as "sign_in"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the column `in_out` identifies the sign in and sign out rows, you can do the following:

```
select si."date" as sign_in
       so."date" as sign_out
from the_table si
  join the_table so 
    on so.shift_id = si.shift_id
   and so.in_out = '02'
where si.in_out = '01'
```

If it's possible to have a sign in without a sign out, you need a `left join` instead of an inner join.